# Which ML algorithms suits better for movie ranking?

Tags: machine-learning, ranking

I am trying to rank a movie based on user ratings. Which algorithm(s) should be used to rank them? I have just stars from 0 to 5 and movie names.
Few movies have a lot of one star and a few a lot of 5

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can either treat this as a bounded regression problem or as a classification problem.  In my experience, classification seems to work better so I would recommend you take that approach.

Comment: I am not sure if thats a valid ML problem. If the data you have is only stars and movie names then you might just sort them based on stars.

Comment: Would you suggest TF ranking ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is too little data (features) to make any ML algorithm perform well. Do you have access to any other features? Such as movie genre, cast and crew, movie length, etc? If you have those data then you can start with a simple neural network. [This paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45530.pdf) might give you some ideas.

Also, before thinking of any ML algorithm, you can think of what are the criteria that impact a movie ranking beyond just user input. That might help you formulate the problem better, come up with some simple heuristics and you might not even need any Machine Learning/Deep Learning algorithms.